# how to construct a list using Linq, while doing something else?

Tags: c#

for example

```
          foreach (var item in List<int> a)
           {
            b.add(item);
            c+=item;
            dosomething();
           }
```

how to write this into Linq form? or is it necessary?

I guess it has the following format: `var b = a.xxxx(x=>(c+=x;dosomething())).ToList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since LINQ is really intended to be a query language, I would say it's bad style to have queries that have secondary effects when they are evaluated. I'd personally either leave things the way they are, or change it to something like this:

```
var c = a.Sum();
var b = a.ToList();
foreach(var item in a)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Even though you end up iterating over the list multiple times, it's much easier to glance at each line of code and know immediately what it does.

Comment: isn't `b=a` the same as `b=a.ToList()`?

Comment: No: `b=a` copies the reference (`a` and `b` now refer to the same list), while `b=a.ToList()` creates a copy of the list (`a` and `b` now refer to different lists that have the same contents).

Comment: @colinfang: This code snippet assumes that `b` is a newly-created list, and since you're adding each item in `a` to it, then you would end up with the same contents as are in `a` at the end of the `for` loop. However, if you wanted to have `b` have additional elements you could use other methods like `Concat`, `Aggregate` to produce exactly the collection you're going for. The point is to make your code declarative. `b = d.Concat(c).ToList()`: "Oh, so `b` is a list with the contents of `d` and `c`."

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
var b = a.Select(i => { c += i; dosomething(); return i; }).ToList();
```

Note that this is probably considered bad practice.  The `foreach` loop is likely more readable and therefore more maintainable.  (It will also be more performant, since there isn't a jump-to-pointer instruction being executed for each item in the list.)